# Why does this margin flows outsite its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a div **mainlogo** inside another div for logo. Now, when I give it margin on top, it flows outside the outer divs. What I want is that when I give it margin-top, it should displace itself downward, instead of flowing its margin outside the parent.

```css
.header {
  width: inherit;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0080FF;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px grey;
}
.headerdiv img {
  width: 80px;
}
.headerdiv {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
}
#mainlogo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="headerdiv">
    <a href="onlinequiz login.php">
      <div id="mainlogo">
        <img src="Images/logo.png"></img>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does it happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: One relatively easy fix is to use padding-top instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky margin spec. [This page](http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/) has a very good explanation of the behavior you are running into. If you don't want to change the `#mainlogo` whitespace to `padding`, you can work around the margin collapse by giving an `overflow: hidden` property to your `.header`.

```css
.header {
  width: inherit;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0080FF;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px 0.5px grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.headerdiv img {
  width: 80px;
}
.headerdiv {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
}
#mainlogo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="headerdiv">
    <a href="onlinequiz login.php">
      <div id="mainlogo">
        <img src="Images/logo.png"></img>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you might consider changing the `#mainlogo` `div` into a `span` and self-closing your `img` tag to avoid unexpected cross-browser quirks.

Comment: Thank you sir, I read and understood that article. That solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

beacuse you are using a generalize DIV's as it is. Use **floating property** i.e. **float:left** there,

and it will work

like this,

```
#mainlogo {
  float:left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: Floating will take the `#mainlogo` out of the document flow and could introduce a whole new set of layout challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... Set the position property of headerdiv to position: absolute;

```
.headerdiv {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}
```